# Why does a default textarea placeholder and an input placeholder get rendered differently?

Tags: html, css, browser

In a simple HTML form- why does a textarea and an input placeholder rendering vary so much in the default case?

Current Firefox and Chrome for example:

[image: A side by side of firefox and chrome rendering placeholders for textearea and inputs1]

```html
<form><input type="text" placeholder="what"><br><textarea placeholder="what"></textarea></form>
```

[image: in a jsfiddle]

Comment: Tested on Firefox 95.0.2 they are rendered the same.

Comment: Interesting, the screenshot is also from 95.0.2 - Windows 10 Home Version 21H2

Comment: See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv4ang7t/). I think it must because one of your CSS that reset its default style.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the box in jsfiddle @vee

Comment: I see the different on Chrome but not Firefox. However, reset the placeholder with css seems to be help. https://jsfiddle.net/14p6yeLf/

Comment: Chrome and Firefox do render differently on my Windows10. Inspecting shows they both set font-family monospace, but the font used is different. The two sans serif used in Chrome are different typefaces and in FF one is sans serif and the other is serif, as shown in the question. I can see nothing in the shadow dom settings that distinguishes the two but the system is certainly picking up different ones.

Comment: Seems it all depends on how the user's browser settings are. So the people here who are seeing rthe same on FF, for example, may have their browser settings the same. Others don't. I've put a bit of description in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing on Edge/Chrome on Windows10 it seems that the preferences for fonts in settings are what influences which font is picked up for the input placeholder and which for the textarea placeholder.

If you go to edge://settings/fonts for example check the settings for sans-serif font and fixed-width font. On my Edge (which had previously not had the settings changed) one was 16pt Arial and the other 13pt Consolas.

Those settings do tally with what I saw as the differences between the placeholder in input element and placeholder in textarea element. And they looked the same as the image given for Chrome in the question (I'd expect Chrome and Edge to be the same).

Now try setting the fixed-width font to Arial.

The input and textarea inputs render the same.

So, what the user sees depends on the settings in their individual browsers and the main takeaway from this seems to be

**You cannot depend on the default settings in a browser to give uniform appearance across browsers, or even the same browser on the same OS as they may have been changed.**

Comment: Thank you (for validating I am not crazy) - I was hoping there'd be any documentation out there about why this choice was made but it just seems like "well we have multiple options so just deal with it"

Comment: Also thank you - after your comment I found the "fonts" tab of the developer tools - for me I am seeing Tahoma vs Courier New... time for a reset.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `<textarea>` is used for multiline intake while the `input` option is used for limited text.